# MySQL Duplicates on Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a chat application where a reference of every conversation is stored in a lookup table called conversations, then it pulls the actual conversations from the messages table but i keep getting duplicated data running this query, any ideas ?

```
    select t2.text
    from conversations as t1
    inner join messages2 t2
    on t1.thread_id = t2.thread_id 
    where t1.user_id = 1
```

// conversations table (lookup)

```
    Schema::create('conversations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('thread_id')->unsigned();            
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();            
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

// messages table

```
    Schema::create('messages2', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('from')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('to')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('thread_id')->unsigned();     
        $table->boolean('read')->default(false);    
        $table->text('text');                                
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: I believe that you are saving two messages row to each message, maybe because each message must have two or more users. Can you select any thread_id at messages table to confirm that. You also can do a select at message table with a group by (thread_id) and return count(*).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are getting duplicates from, but you should try the `DISTINCT` function

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.text
    FROM conversations AS t1
    INNER JOIN messages2 t2
    ON t1.thread_id = t2.thread_id 
    WHERE t1.user_id = 1
```

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but here ya go: 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp